# android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin. Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead. Affected Modules:

Tags: android, gradle

ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.3.0-alpha01] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-55:19 to override.

sync failed 3 m 47 s 812 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon  25 s 226 ms
Run build   1 m 50 s 579 ms
null
C:/Users/kashem/Desktop/Project/TestSms 
app/build.gradle
android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin.  Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.
Affected Modules: app
API 'variant.getJavaCompiler()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getJavaCompiler(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
Affected Modules: app
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed soon. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.3.0-alpha01] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-55:19 to override.

Comment: Are you using kotlin ?

Comment: no,use only java

Comment: Its import on desktop file